# Accordian menu (when clicked) affects position of an image in the next table cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I'm using an accordion menu I found on a CSS resource page.

The menu works fine - the only problem is:

I have an image that's right next to the menu (the image and the accordion menu are in their own separate table cell), and whenever the accordion menu is clicked, the image will shift downwards along with the accordion effect.

I basically need the image to stay where it is (valign middle) and not move around whenever the accordion menu is clicked.

I have very bare basic knowledge of HTML and this is issue is driving me nuts :(

Hope someone can help me out - thank you in advance!

**This is the CSS:**

```
.container { 
    width:360px; 
    font-family:'Varela Round', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 0 20px;
}
.accordion {
    font-size:13px;
    border-radius:10px;
    width:360px;
    padding:10px;
    background:none;
}
.accordion ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}
.accordion li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.accordion [type=radio], .accordion [type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
.accordion label {
    display:block;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:16px;
    background:#10967a;
    color:#ffffff;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-out;
}
.accordion ul li label:hover, .accordion [type=radio]:checked ~ label, .accordion [type=checkbox]:checked ~ label {
    background:#39bc86;
    color:#FFF;
}
.accordion .content {
    padding:0 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #fff; /* Make the border match the background so it fades in nicely */
    background:#FFFFFF;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
.accordion p {
    color:#333;
    margin:0 0 10px;
}
.accordion h3 {
    color:#542437;
    padding:0;
    margin:10px 0;
}


/* Vertical */
.vertical ul li {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 0 1px;
}
.vertical ul li label {
    padding:8px;
}
.vertical [type=radio]:checked ~ label, .vertical [type=checkbox]:checked ~ label {
    border-bottom:0;
}

.vertical ul li .content {
    height:0px;
    border-top:0;
}
.vertical [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content, .vertical [type=checkbox]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
    height:250px;

}
```

**This is the HTML:**

```
<body>
<table width="1010" border="0" background="images/bg.jpg">
  <tr>
    <td height="380" align="left" valign="top"><table width="1010" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="56">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="320"><table width="100%" border="1">
          <tr>
            <td><img src="../images/pdt_01.jpg" width="181" height="205" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
        <td width="360" valign="top"><div class="container">
          <div class="accordion vertical">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" name="checkbox-accordion" />
                <label for="checkbox-1"><strong><span class="text">ADDRESSES</span></strong></label>
                <div class="content">
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="8">
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top" class="list">6767 S Clinton St</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top" class="list">16910 E Quincy Ave</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top" class="list">5010 Founders Pkwy</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top" class="list">9390 W Cross Dr</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top" class="list">1985 Sheridan Blvd</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top" class="list">1630 E Cheyenne Mountain Blvd</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  </div>
                </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" name="checkbox-" />
                <label for="checkbox-2"><strong><span class="text"><a href="3" target="_blank">MORE</a></span></strong></label>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div></td>
        <td width="350">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Are there any other info that you need?

Comment: The way you currently have it set up will not work. This isn't an answer per say only because an answer would involved redoing your code.

Your code as of right now is working exactly as you are telling it to. As your menu "expands" it is increasing the height of the table. Since you have the picture aligning to the middle of the height, it will move as the table increases in size to stay centered.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that image is valign="middle", so it's working fine B'coz whenever menu expands table height also increases with menu and image is adjusting itself in the middle.

but you can try `valign="top"` in "td" which is holding the image table . like below

```
<td width="320" valign="top">
    <table width="100%" border="1">
       <tr>
         <td><img src="../images/pdt_01.jpg" width="181" height="205" /></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

if it is not necessary to make it valign="middle" you can use it...

**http://jsfiddle.net/t8NDN/**